# Getting blank sender email id using Imap4

Tags: python, django, office365, imap

I am getting header 'from' blank i.e. unable to get sender address

```
c.select('INBOX', readonly=True)

for i in range(1, 30):
    typ, msg_data = c.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)')
    for response_part in msg_data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
            for header in [ 'subject', 'to', 'from' ]:
                print '%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), msg[header])
```

Here is the output

SUBJECT : Here is testing subject

TO      : "abhi.don@gdp.gov"

FROM    :

**Edit 1**

Even I am not getting message id i.e. message id is also blank.
I even try this code also

```
typ, data = mb.fetch(num_id, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)])')  
msg_str = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])  
message_id = msg_str.get('Message-ID')  
print message_id
```

Comment: Does the message actually have a From header?  It could be missing!

Comment: Yes the message actually have a From header which is blank. office365
To: "abhi.don@gdp.gov" <abhi.don@gdp.gov>
Bcc: someone hidden <someone.hidden@mine.com>
From:
Subject: Here is testing subject
Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 16:06:50 -0400

Comment: So, if the From header is blank, why would you expect the output not to be blank?

Comment: Apologies! Max. I interpreted wrongly. I can see message's From header at office365 mailing account. But, I am not receiving it in Response Header of Imap4.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in fetching the entire message RFC 5322 plaintext serialization to read the `From` field. Have a look at RFC 3501, consult the `BODYSTRUCTURE` field and use the data from there. Remember to apply RFC 2047 decoding to get real Unicode text.

Comment: I am using this code since 2 years and now for particular this office365's account I am getting blank error. @Jan Could you please help me through code? or let me know where I am wrong.